# login and logout cause dead cycle

Tags: django

I create a custom authentication backend for two different type of users. Users can login and logout with their account. However, sometime it cause a infinite loop. What is the possible reason to cause such error?

The partial of error in console:

```
"[06/Jul/2016 07:53:41] "GET /dataInfo/login/?next=/dataInfo/login/%3Fnext%3D/dataInfo/login/%253Fnext%253D/dataInfo/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[06/Jul/2016 07:53:41] "GET /dataInfo/login/?next=/dataInfo/login/%3Fnext%3D/dataInfo/login/%253Fnext%253D/dataInfo/login/%25253Fnext%25253D/dataInfo/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[06/Jul/2016 07:53:41] "GET /dataInfo/login/?next=/dataInfo/login/%3Fnext%3D/dataInfo/login/%253Fnext%253D/dataInfo/login/%25253Fnext%25253D/dataInfo/login/%2525253Fnext%2525253D/dataInfo/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"
```

In my views

```
@login_required(login_url='/dataInfo/login/')
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(name=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                #redirect to user profile
                print "suffcessful login!"

                # chech the user type 
                # if it is Customer,redirect to sale view
                # if it is Staff,redirect to userprofile
                if request.user.get_user_type() == "Customer":
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/dataInfo/sale_view')
                if request.user.get_user_type() == "Staff":
                    # set permission to user
                    request.user.asgin_perm("add_store")
                    request.user.asgin_perm("add_product")
                    request.user.asgin_perm("add_sale")
                    request.user.asgin_perm("change_store")
                    request.user.asgin_perm("change_product")
                    request.user.asgin_perm("change_sale")
                    request.user.asgin_perm("delete_store")
                    request.user.asgin_perm("delete_product")
                    request.user.asgin_perm("delete_sale")

                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/dataInfo/userprofile')
            else:
                # return a disable account
                return HttpResponse("User acount or password is incorrect")
        else:
            print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/dataInfo/login')
    else:

        login_form = LoginForm()
    return render_to_response('dataInfo/login.html', {'form': login_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required(login_url='/dataInfo/login/')
def logout_view(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/dataInfo/login')
```

In my backend

```
from .models import Customer,Staff
from django.conf import settings

class CustomerAuthBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, name=None, password=None):
        try:

            user = Customer.objects.get(name=name)

            if password == getattr(user,'password'):

                user.is_active = True
                # print "is_active: %s" %user.is_active
                return user
            else:
                # Authentication fails if None is returned
                return None
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return Customer.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        # TODO: may delete
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            return None

class StaffAuthBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, name=None, password=None):
        try:
            # TODO : check User is None
            user = Staff.objects.get(name=name)

            if password == getattr(user,'password'):

                Staff.is_active = True

                return user
            else:
                return None
        except Staff.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return Staff.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        # TODO: may delete
        except Staff.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Answer (score 1):

Your login view requires you to be logged in (`@login_required`)

So you can never possibly log in because you need to be logged in to log in, but you're not logged in so you can't log in because you can't get to the page to let you log in.

So if you want to be able to login you need to remove the decorator so your login view will not require you to be logged in to be logged in, because after all,  if you were logged in then you wouldn't be trying to login.

Comment: You mean that I should delete login_required decorator in my login view.

Comment: @pipi - No worries, you may also want to just specify the `LOGIN_URL` in your settings so you don't need to pass it to every decorator

Comment: I have the other question,it is not very related to this question. In my code, I assign permission in my login view? I am mot sure this is the suitable place to set permission. What is the common place to set permission for a custom user.

Comment: @pipi - You should raise a new question complete with what you have tried and researched for that. Even then it may still be opinion based, require more information, and potentially off-topic. I'd imagine it should be when the user is registered, or when a new permission is required, but hard to say